# Electrical - LED E14 size light bulbs not working in European Chandelier

Tags: electrical, led

We have a European chandelier that takes 6 E14 size bulbs.  We currently use incandescent bulbs without issue, but we would like to switch to LEDs.  We bought some LED bulbs, but they don't work - they just don't light up at all.  We do not use a dimmer switch. The LED bulbs are definitely the correct size - E14.  Does anyone know why the LED bulbs don't work?  The light fixture is an antique, probably from the 60's with original European wiring.

Comment: try putting in all incandescents and one led to see if that works

Comment: Thanks, I tried that as well as multiple combinations of both types of bulbs.  The incandescent bulbs always work, but never the LEDs.

Comment: More than likely the tips of the LED light bases are shorter and are not making contact in the socket. **With the circuit breaker off or fuse removed**, try carefully bending up the socket center contact with a small screwdriver.

Comment: Incandescent bulbs are generally expected to have a long neck.  Some LED bulbs "flare out" near the base to accommodate the driver circuit.  CFLs do the same thing.  This flare often physically strikes part of the fixture, allowing the screws to engage, but not allowing the center nub to "bottom out".  It feels tight, but it's not all the way down.

Comment: Do the LEDs work in other fixtures?